# Apache HttpClient doesn't get content of pages using pagination links. I get 200 status but html has no content

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to web crawl pages of content with Apache HttpClient. I get status 200 when requesting the next page using the link from pagination but HTML shows 500 in the body and no content. Postman works fine and gets content even when using links from pagination.

Main class

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/reviews/topics";
        MyContentFetcher myContentFetcher = new MyContentFetcher();
        MyParser myParser = new MyParser();
        try {
            // Load Topic list page
            String topicsPage = myContentFetcher.loadHTML(url);

            // Getting all the topics.
            Map<Integer, MyNode> topics = myParser.getTopicList(topicsPage);

            // Print all the topics and ask user to choose one
            for (int id : topics.keySet())
                System.out.println("-> " + id + " <- " + topics.get(id).getTopic());
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.print("Enter ID number from the list above to get reviews or enter anything else to exit:\n");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String id = reader.readLine();

            // Validate user input, get the link and topic and cout the choice.
            if (isNumber(id)) {
                int idNum = Integer.parseInt(id);
                if (idNum <= topics.size() && idNum > 0) {
                    String topic = topics.get(idNum).getTopic();
                    String link = topics.get(idNum).getLink();
                    System.out.println("You picked: " + topic + link + "\n***************************");
                    // Loading first page of reviews
                    myParser.loadReviews(myContentFetcher.loadHTML(link), topic);
                    // Getting links to other pages
                    Queue<String> paginationLinks = myParser.getLinks();

                    // --------------> WORKS FINE UNTIL HERE <--------------
                    // Problem starts here....
                    // Load list of reviews for chosen topic
                    while(!paginationLinks.isEmpty()) {
                        String page = myContentFetcher.loadHTML(paginationLinks.remove());
                        myParser.loadReviews(page, topic);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Exiting...");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem...");
        }
```

!!!! Here is the class that fetches HTML. I'm probably doing something wrong here...

```java
import org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyContentFetcher {

    public MyContentFetcher() {
    }

    String loadHTML(String url) throws IOException {
        // Create configurations for
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                .build();
        // Creating a HttpClient object
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .build();
        // Creating a HttpGet object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Pixel Build/OPM4.171019.021.D1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.109 Mobile Safari/537.36 EdgA/42.0.0.2057");
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
        StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder("");
        while(sc.hasNext())
            page.append(sc.nextLine()).append(" ");
        httpResponse.close();
        httpClient.close();
        return page.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the parser. Parser doesn't have any problems (Parse perfectly fine and as needed)

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class MyParser {

    private Map<String, String> topics;
    private Document htmlPage;
    private Element reviewBlock;

    public MyParser(){}

    // Loads all topics from the Cochrane Library into a map -> (Topic Name, Link)
    public Map<Integer, MyNode> getTopicList(String page) {
        Map<Integer, MyNode> topics= new HashMap<Integer, MyNode>();
        htmlPage = Jsoup.parse(page);
        // Get 'a' element that is inside 'li' with a class name of browse-by-list-item
        int i = 1;
        MyNode info;
        for(Element element : htmlPage.body().select("li.browse-by-list-item > a")) {
            info = new MyNode(element.select("button").text(),
                    element.select("a").attr("href").trim());
            topics.put(i, info);
            i++;
        }
        return topics;
    }

    // Loads Reviews
    public void loadReviews(String page, String topic) throws IOException {
        htmlPage = Jsoup.parse(page);
        // Get all review blocks
        System.out.println("**************************\n" + page + "\n**************************\n");
        for(Element element : htmlPage.body().select(".search-results-item-body")){
            reviewBlock = element;
            String review = getLink() + " | " + topic + " | " + getTitle() + " | " + getAuthor() + " | " + getDate();
            System.out.println(review);
        }
    }

    Queue<String> getLinks(){
        System.out.println("GETTING LINKS");
        Queue<String> links = new LinkedList<>();
        for(Element element : htmlPage.body().select("li.pagination-page-list-item > a")) {
            links.add(element.attr("href"));
        }
        return links;
    }

    private String getLink(){
        return "https://www.cochranelibrary.com" + reviewBlock.select("a").attr("href");
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return reviewBlock.selectFirst("a").text();
    }

    public String getAuthor(){
        return reviewBlock.selectFirst("div.search-result-authors").text();
    }

    public String getDate(){
        String result = reviewBlock.select("div.search-result-date > div").text();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.US);
            Date d = fmt.parse(result);
            fmt.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            result = fmt.format(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed parsing the date...");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Any help is truly appreciated. It's my first project using Apache HttpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I created a session and used cookie store and used CloseableHttpResponse to close the response after each time I fetch the page. Here is the fragment of the code that make it work:

```java
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
                .build();
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(100)
                .build();
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        httpContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Whatever");
        StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder("");
        try {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget, httpContext);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent());
            while (sc.hasNext())
                page.append(sc.nextLine()).append(" ");
            sc.close();
            response.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return page.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had I had the permissions, this would have been just a comment.
I ran your `loadHtml` function with the URL you provided and the result I get is more or less equal to the html of the page.

Could you please provide more details about the `httpclient` library? I'm using Java 12 (I'm positive it would work with Java 8 too) with this dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I used the 4.5.+.